# What is the confusion about my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have placed the question *[How to load a single JSON file into a SproutCore model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538072)* on the Stack Overflow site. Even though I have googled about it or searched on Stack Exchange, I didn't get sufficient leads or approaches to try. I have explained the same in the question under the heading *Research that I have done*.

However I am surprised to see one of answerer asked "What you have tried". I don't understand, what does it mean? Am I not clear in my explanation? Or does that user expect some other things to do?

Comment: People would like to see what code you tried - that's what they mean.

Comment: @Oded: I didn't have any approach or any lead or any direction to try. Thats why I didn't try with any code.

Comment: However, that's part of research in the software world. Try _something_.

Comment: @oded: What else we can try before asking in SE and after done with google search?

Comment: @BVR, consider this: without knowing what code you tried, how can we know what knowledge you have? Also, the answerer has given you some starting points, but all you added is "I don't have any code"?

Comment: @Arjan: I do agree with you. But my question is without having any leads or approaches or direction what can I code? How can I code?

Comment: In that case you might simply have to do more research until you've got something. If you are still in your early research phase, SO might not be the best venue for your question. That said, your question is not yet closed, so keep researching.

Comment: @BVR: the person who answered had to make guesses about quite a few things before they could even start to answer. Your question should include those details at least.

Comment: @Mat: I do agree with you. Thanks for bringing the point. However the focus is more on what else I could have to try before coming to SE?

Comment: @Bart: Thanks for your inputs. But At what point we can judge that I am still in early phases of research or we have done sufficient research and now it is eligible to take the help of experts? But that said I haven't stopped research. Searching for more and more approaches.

Comment: @BVR: not really. It's all a group of things. If you come with an under-specified question with no evidence that you've done some research, you're even worse of than just with no evidence of research. And "I have searched but found nothing" is not _evidence_ of research. Show what you found and explain why it doesn't work/what you don't understand.

Comment: I feel like change the question scope and title to "What else we can try before asking in SE and after done with google search?". Is it better option to create altogether new thread?

Comment: @Mat: Hmm. You mean giving list of articles that I have found and explaining why those are not answering my question. Is it productive? Suppose If I have found 10 pages of results and each page has 10 links. Explaining about each link why it is not answering my question makes the thread bulge. Does that really serves the purpose?

Comment: None of those 100 pages even gave you a clue as to how to start?

Comment: @Mat: We are deviating from the right track. I have specified as generic example. Does that mean it is applicable to the given situation specified in this thread. Anyways I am feeling your questions and answers are dragging the focus from main point.

Comment: No we're not. Surely if you found 100 pages related to your issue (i.e. you've done some serious research), you've at least found hints about what you should be using/doing, even if you can't figure the whole thing out yourself. State that you found these hints but can't complete the task with only those. Obviously don't post 100 links with a research brief on each - one or two of the potential routes is enough to show you've actually done some work.

Comment: @Mat: I got the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @BVR what do you mean you "got the answer", are you talking about this question, the question on SO (or something else)? Perhaps you could help other users by adding an answer to the appropriate question?

Comment: @Hayden: I got the answer for my question. As Mat suggested I have to state the main or potential hints that I have found and try on that direction and explain why those are not worked

Comment: @BVR, often the questions are underspecified in that relevant data (operating system, versions, network configuration, ...) aren't given. Trying to answer such is just a (frustrating) exercise in wild guessing. No fun in that.

Answer (score 5):

In the discussion I have found the answer and I would like to document here for the benefit of other members. If any person would seriously searched in the surely they would come across multiple results which provides many hints. So we have to take main and potential and most relevant links and get the hints and try to find solution for it. If it doesn't help much quote those few hints while posting question in SE and explain why those are not help to solve the issue that we are facing.  This will helps us to show evidence that we have done enough research. Other wise it is easy other person to think that we haven't done any research and still claiming saying that we have done research.

For the above question, I am simply stating"

> *I have searched in Google with the phrase "How to load single JSON into SproutCore model?". However, I didn't get any results which answer my question. I have also searched on Stack Overflow. But I didn't get any results here either.*

This statement is so generic and not showing any evidence. Hence other person asked "what you have tried". The take out from this discussion is I have to show constructive evidence in order to get help from SE members

Answer (score 1):

On the positive side, it's commendable that you've at least made some effort into showing what you have done *before* asking a question on the site.

Granted, Sproutcore being relatively new, the [FAQ list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sproutcore?sort=faq) is somewhat paltry in comparison to the bigger frameworks, but the project itself has a pretty extensive [guide section](http://guides.sproutcore.com/).

Ways for improvement:

1. Your prior research should at least yield some starting point based on things you can find on either SO or the project site itself.
2. Reference the chief documents that helped you get as far as you did.
3. Statements such as "This answer got me close, but ..." are great.

Keep in mind that the above improvements help the people who will be answering your question, but perhaps more importantly, those who stumble upon your question later.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close but missing a few vital pieces.

First, programmers that answer questions on SO would generally rather "Teach a man to fish" than simply hand you fish for dinner.  Certainly not all are like that, but enough are that this is important.

In order to Teach a man to fish, it is usually a good idea to understand whether that man even knows what a fishing pole is.  Once we've established a baseline of knowledge then we can more readily help.

The second piece is that a lot of those answering questions may never have done exactly what it is you are doing but can certainly help with giving alternative approaches or even simply seeing that one piece you are missing.  We might even have better GoogleFu skills, as long as there is a starting point.  A lot of us have day jobs and can't spend hours putting together a fully functional test case for your issue.  However, most of us can lend a few minutes to correct items or point you in the right direction when there is something to work with.

---

In your referenced question, you mention you want to use SproutCore; however, there is absolutely no code or direction in how it's usage is necessary.

My question to you would be: have you even looked through the SproutCore API to figure this out?  If not, then see #1 above.  If you have, then post what interesting thing you've found AND the code you tried to get it to work.

My next question would be: why SproutCore?  If you don't know if it will accomplish your goals, then why are you tying yourself to it?  In other words, what other dependencies exist that you haven't referenced in your question?  This line of questioning is only important if you haven't looked through SproutCore.

As others, and yourself, have noted simply saying "I looked all other the internet and couldn't find an answer" isn't enough.

---

The summary here is that there is almost no information to go by in order to answer your question.  So, you got lucky that hvgotcodes was able to make a few assumptions and give you a few lines to get you going.